# Picture in body email PYTHON on Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, email

The crux of the matter, I need to embed a picture in the body of the letter (exactly in the letter itself, and not as an attachment to the letter) in python. I use Linux (Ubuntu)
Plus, everything needs to align the text and this picture in the center of my letter.
Also attach a hyperlink to one more picture to make the picture clickable.
I hope I expressed everything as fully and intelligibly as possible, I am very, very weak in coding, but I am trying to become the best)
I will attach a part of the code:

````
    "subject_header": bytes("Subject: КотБегемотэуэуэуэ\r\n", 'utf-8'), # Subject: hellso\r\n 
    "to_header": b"", # To: <sdkloi989dsaipyhtetere@gmail.com>\r\n 
    "body": bytes("<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title> 
</head> 
<body> 
  <img src='/home/mkljuhjgh67888/kilujh111/lk787y.png'> 
</body> 
</html>\r\n", 'utf-8'), # Test Body. 
    # Optional. "raw_email": b"", }```

Asked a question earlier, one person advised to insert THIS in "body": bytes ("...
But nothing came of it, gave this error: "body": bytes ("Syntax Error: EOL while scanning string literal

P.S. Ubuntu 20.04
````